# Regular expression to match whole string but case insentitive

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of codes that I loop through, and for each code I need to check for an exact but ***non-case sensitive*** match when a form is submitted.

I hva come up with a solution using a regular expression, but it's not quite perfect (it ignores case, but it will return partial matches).

For example, take this sample from my list of codes -

> EXC
>   EXD
>   EXD1

If `ex` is submitted no matches should be found (but all 3 examples are matched), and if `exd` is submitted only `EXD` should be matched (but `EXD1` is also matched).

In the code below `val` is the user input from the form and `v.code` is each looped code -

```
if(v.code.search(new RegExp(val, "i")) >= 0){ ...
```

How can I amend this code to meet my requirements? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the regular expression with start and end anchors:

```
if (new RegExp("^" + val + "$", "i").test(v.code)) {
  // match!
}
```

If you're worried about performance should there be a whole lot of codes to test, you could pre-construct the regular expressions so that you don't have to do so for each validation.

Comment: Permormance wise, there will be about 200 codes. By pre-construct i assume you mean `var regexp = new RegExp(...);` and the use `if(regexp.test(v.code))`?

Comment: @DavidGard right - just build an array of regex objects to go along with the set of codes, or add another property to the "v" objects. Again, since this seems like a validation thing that happens when a user clicks something, it may be plenty fast enough without worrying about that, so try the simple version first.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without regex at all by:

```
if (val.toLowerCase() == "insensitive string".toLowerCase())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good point. I would probably do it this way if I were really looking for exact matches, because it avoids the potential issues with regex metacharacters.

Comment: I love to avoid regex if they don't add something but unfortunately converting to lower case is **not culture safe** (of course it may work in **this case** if OP has to compare only us ASCII characters). In your example `"I".toLowerCase() != "i".toLowerCase()` for Turkish. It doesn't handle all locale related issues (eszett in German, for example) but a little bit better is to use `toLocaleLowerCase()`.

Comment: Good point, this is a good one to have in the bank for the future. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundaries:

```
new RegExp('\\b'+val+'\\b', "i")
```

Comment: @DavidGard: Sorry, the `\b` must be escaped: `\\b`